# Is there a way to raise a cplex expression (docplex.mp.LinearExpr(...)) to the power -1 or 3 in python?

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, quadratic-programming

I have constructed a linear programming problem in Python and use the CPLEX solver. The variables are expressed as cplex expressions like docplex.mp.LinearExpr(...). The goal is to construct an objective where we optimize over a variable with an expression like that to the power -1 or 3:

**Opt** 1/variable

Unfortunately, I receive the following error message;
docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexException: Cannot raise "docplex.mp.LinearExpr(...)" to the power -1. A variable's exponent must be 0, 1 or 2.

Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this problem? So is there a way to divide a certain number by a value equivalent to docplex.mp.LinearExpr(...)?

Comment: Please share what code you have written so far so that the community can analyze it and provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Erwin is correct as always. However in some limited cases you maybe able to rearrange your expressions to avoid dividing by a variable, e.g. change `a <= 1 / var` to `a * var <= 1`. Without seeing more of your model we cannot know if this kind of simple rearrangement could work for you.

Comment: Counter example: `var=-1`

Answer (score 0):

No, Cplex can only do linear and quadratic models. It is not a general-purpose nonlinear solver.

Note that: *I have constructed a linear programming problem* is not really true. This is now becoming a non-linear model.